# WSO2-APIM Analytics : Can we export raw data to excel or csv?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am currently experimenting with WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 Analytics features. I have question as following.

1. If I want to query raw data (not the summary data) from APIM Analytics is this the correct URL for the documentation about the API?[https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+REST+API+Guide]
2. Is there feature to export raw data from APIM Analytics table to excel or csv file without having to write program to call the provided API?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers below.

1. To configure analytics for APIM 2.0.0, you are using API Manager Analytics distribution as described in [API Manager docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics). The documentation that you refer is DAS 3.0.0 that gives you the DAS REST API to explore the data.
   In API Manager analytics, it is using the RDBMS approach and you can use the Data Explorer in Management Console of API Manager Analytics distribution to explore data. It consist of some filters too.

[image]

After login to the API Manager Analytics, go to Manage   > Interactive Analytics     > Data Explorer to view raw data.

2. WSO2 API Manager do not have the capability of exporting raw data directly to CSVs. You can use SQL commands on tables of raw data to export them as CSVs.